# Ksh/Bash script to run commands based on kernel name

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, ksh

I am trying to build a script that will take all hostnames from a file and run various commands depending on the kernel name.

I first want to ssh to the host machine and after issuing an `uname -a` command I want to send a specific set of commands depending on the OS Version using **case**

What I've done so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for ssh_host in $(cat hostsFile)
do
    echo $ssh_host
    kernel=`ssh $ssh_host "uname -a"`
    echo $kernel

case $kernel in
        "Linux")
                echo "This is Linux"
                ;;

    "AIX")
            echo "This is AIX"
    ;;
    *)
            echo "Not sure what this is"
    ;;
esac
done
```

I'm stuck where I should check if the string "Linux" is present in the `uname -a` output from the $kernel variable.

Comment: Have you tried `uname -o` ? Also `uname -s` gives directly the kernel name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make your patterns less exact: search for the word *somewhere* in the text

```
case $kernel in
    *Linux*) echo "This is Linux" ;;
    *AIX*)   echo "This is AIX"   ;;
    *)       echo "Not sure what this is: $kernel" ;;
esac
```

Also, you can be more specific, at least with GNU uname

```
$ uname -s
Linux
```

You'd have to check the AIX uname man page to see if there's the same option there.

Comment: The $kernel variable will be something like: **Linux boxName3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux** - are you sure this will work? Regarding the uname -s, there is no such argument on AIX so I'd prefer using uname -a as every *unix system knows that.

Comment: Yes it will work. Did you try it?